# MPDF and PHP on server

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a big problem with mPDF. And it is that being on the local server everything works correctly, but when uploading it to a GoDaddy (Hosting) server when loading the page where I have the code to generate the PDF I get **HTTP ERROR 500**.

I start to make some changes because I thought it was my code, and then I managed to verify that no, I comment on the line where I charge the library (**$ mpdf = new \ Mpdf \ Mpdf ();**) and modify some things just to show with ECHO, and It charges me all normal.

```
require '../lib/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$auditpdf=base64_decode($_GET["pdfID"]);
$html ='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Only that is the code apart from some things that I cannot show for confidentiality. I hope you help me.

Comment: What does the server error log show? That is where 500 errors go.

Comment: @Dave ,The funny thing is that the server log shows absolutely nothing. The error shows me in the browser, it is as if I did not load the library.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error and would have been logged unless something is not configured correctly. My guess would be that you are not looking at the correct error log or that GoDaddy isn't showing you the actual log (not likely). Try checking their FAQs to find out how to look at the raw log file for the server.

Comment: @Dave [05-Feb-2020 20:02:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: mbstring extension must be loaded in order to run mPDF in /home/miserver/public_html/panel/miserver/lib/mpdf/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php:9513
Stack trace:
#0 /home/miserver/public_html/panel/miserver/lib/mpdf/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1021): Mpdf\Mpdf->_dochecks()
#1 /home/miserver/public_html/panel/miserver/modules/genpdf.php(7): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/miserver/public_html/panel/miserver/lib/mpdf/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php on line 9513

Comment: @Dave You were right, the error is that it does not load the extension mbstring

Answer (score 1):

**I already fixed the error.**
This is how I fixed it:
It turns out that the vps I hired did not have the **mbstring** extension installed, I immediately went to install the extension on my server, how did I do it? Ok, I entered my godaddy account and entered my server, then in the menu select software followed of **easyapache** there in the profiles we only customize the default (so I did) we go to the extensions step, we look for the **mbstring** extension and we install it for the php version that we are going to use.

Once doing that it gave me another error is the **PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33660000 bytes)**.

I fixed it by entering the php ini configuration, but it turns out that godaddy had left me the memory limit allowed in **64M** and later I changed it to **256M** and that's it, so my problem was fixed.